# ElasticSearch Java hangs in initializing state

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm running a default config elasticsearch instance (version 1.7.0) on ubuntu and started it without problems. I can connect to it with Sense for example

My Java client can't seem to connect to it though and hangs after just two messages:

```
2015-07-30 14:47:37,686 INFO : [Masque] version[1.7.0], pid[27317], build[929b973/2015-07-16T14:31:07Z]
2015-07-30 14:47:37,686 INFO : [Masque] initializing ...
```

The elasticsearch log does not show errors or hints to any failed connection attempts.

Locally the same setup works flawlessly (on a Windows machine though).

Any idea of how I could find out more / any logs / any known issues?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: some code might help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so just in case somebody else runs into the same problem. On linux I had to change the way I initialize the client.

First I had

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
client = node.client();
```

which worked on Windows but not on ubuntu. There I had to specifically mention the host and port.

```
client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost",9300));
```